# npm start unable to find JSON file

Tags: npm

I just reinstalled node with the package from their website and cloned an old project. I'm trying to run `npm start` but i'm getting an error stack.

> tweety@0.1.0 start /Users/username/Code/projects/phase-3/lil-twitter-react-challenge/tweety
>   react-scripts start

```
sh: react-scripts: command not found

npm ERR! Darwin 16.6.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "start"
npm ERR! node v6.11.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! tweety@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the tweety@0.1.0 start script 'react-scripts start'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the tweety package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     react-scripts start
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs tweety
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls tweety
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/username/tweety/npm-debug.log
```

Inside my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "tweety",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-scripts": "1.0.7"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.5.4",
    "react-dom": "^15.5.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

The files inside my project (`tweety`) are:

`README.md     npm-debug.log package.json  public        src`

And this is a folder within a Rails app (trying to parse stuff from a rails app and make components from it and run it in a react app).

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you run `npm install` to install all dependencies prior to start you app?

Comment: Facepalm. That was it... Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to run `npm install` to install all dependencies prior to start you app.